# How to add a new navigation button in telerik radwizard

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to add a new navigation button in telerik radwizard([reference](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/wizard/structure/radwizard-element-)). Is there any way to do so in ASP.NET, I read all the documents shared by telerik but couldn't find a way to achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirement as to what you trying to achieve with custom button?

Comment: @fujiFX : In Radwizard there are four navigation buttons(i.e. Next, Previous, Cancel and Finish) which is provided by telerik. I want to add one more navigation button, how can I achieve the same?

Comment: How did go about with this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar requirement, but was not able to find a out of the box solution to include a custom navigation button for the Telerik RadWizard.

Please in-cooperate the the below JavaScript, which would to add a custom button to the navigation button area:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* NOTE: This code block is inserted at this location, but not in the main Script block within RadCodeClock at the begining of this page due to the the below error;
    'JavaScript runtime error: '$telerik' is undefined' 

    In order to avoid such errors, move the script tag below the declaration of the ScriptManager.
    */
    var $ = $telerik.$;
    var oldInitializeEvents = Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizard.prototype._initializeEvents;
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizard.prototype._initializeEvents = function () {
        /*var myLi = $('<li>', { "class": "rwzLI rwzRight" }).appendTo('.rwzNav');          // Add the button adjacent to Next/ Previous*/
        var myLi = $('<li>', { "class": "rwzLI" }).appendTo('.rwzNav');                     // Add the button adjacent to Cancel/ Submit
        var spanElement = $('<span>').addClass("rwzText").text("Save");
        $("<button>", {
            "id": "rwCustNavBtn_Save", "class": "rwzButton", "type": "button", click: function myfunction() {
                CustNavBtn_Save_OnClick();                                                 // Save the Grant
                return false;
            }
        }).append(spanElement).appendTo(myLi);
        oldInitializeEvents.call(this);
    }
</script>
```

**Note**:

1. Ensure to include the above JavaScript tag below the declaration of the ScriptManager, to avoid runtime errors.
2. *rwzRight* CSS class determine the location of the custom button and make use it based on your requirement (refer the comments within the script tag)

Hope this is what you are after and **Mark as Reply** if so. Good luck!

Source: [RadWziard navigation button templates/control](https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/212032-radwziard-navigation-button-templates-control)